# Associativity proof on Nats vs. Lists

Tags: isabelle, proofs

I am comparing the associativity proofs for [Nats](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/Nat.html) and [Lists](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/List.html).

The proof on Lists goes by induction

```
lemma append_assoc [simp]: "(xs @ ys) @ zs = xs @ (ys @ zs)"
by (induct xs) auto
```

But, the proof on Nats is

```
lemma nat_add_assoc: "(m + n) + k = m + ((n + k)::nat)"
by (rule add_assoc)
```

Why do I not need induction on the `nat_add_assoc` proof? Is it because of some automation happening on natural numbers?

Comment: Why are you looking at source code from the Isabelle2013 distribution and not at the up to date files from Isabelle2017?

Comment: Good point! Just because the Isabelle2013 came up when I searched for the proofs. Let me update my search.

Answer (score 5):

The associativity proof on `nat` is also done by induction.

In [Nat.thy](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013/dist/library/HOL/Nat.html) you can find

```
instantiation nat :: comm_monoid_diff
```

which is the Isabelle way of saying `nat` has type class `comm_monoid_diff`. The following definitions and lemmas then show that the natural numbers are a commutative monoid under addition and that there's also subtraction.

In this block you find the proof:

```
instance proof
  fix n m q :: nat
  show "(n + m) + q = n + (m + q)" by (induct n) simp_all
```

The instantiation then gives us the lemma `add_assoc` on `nat`.

Comment: Well, this still does not explain how the same proof can be done without explicit use of the induct strategy.

Comment: When you write `rule add_assoc`, that means you just apply the theorem `add_assoc`. Basically, you're using a theorem that has been proven elsewhere. As ammbauer pointed out, *that* proof *was* done by induction, so of course you don't have to do the induction again. In fact, I'm not sure why `nat_add_assoc` even exists since it's literally the same thing as `add_assoc` specialised to `nat`. Probably historic reasons.

Comment: oh, thanks! It makes sense! It is shadowing the names! I though it was doing a recursive call on the theorem to be proved!

Comment: There is no shadowing going on, as `nat_add_assoc` and `add_assoc` are not the same.